# Scroll only one Colum in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello friends I have one question about bootstrap, this is my html I have the following structure

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    
   </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-8">
    
  </div>
```

How could I get that only "col-md-8" can scroll down? I want that col-md-4 can be shown always and doesn´t scroll down like a fixed menu but I haven´t a fixed menu in col-md-4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simplest way to get it is follow:

```css
.frm {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
.content {
    height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
       col-sm-4
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 frm">
        <div class="content">some content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may not fix height of `.content`. It will work anyway

Comment: Thanks, it´s work but I have now two scrolls in the web, is it possible to join in one?

Comment: does it happen on small vieport?